# Disable apt upgrades globally

Tags: apt

I know that via `apt-mark hold <packagename>` you can disable upgrades for a specific package.

Is there a way to disable / freeze the `apt upgrade` globally?

P.S: I do not want to disable automatic updates; I want to permanently lock the process of `apt upgrade`.

I am launching a custom AMI on EC2 and the `cloudt-init` module performs an upgrade which I want to prevent by passing the appropriate command to `user-data`

Comment: Do you still want to be able to install packages with `apt install`?

Comment: no it is a completely static EC2 instance that I spin up periodically; I do not ever want to run `apt-anything`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you never need `apt`, you *can* remove it — it’s not a required or [essential](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#essential-packages) package, “merely” [important](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#priorities). `apt` itself will loudly complain if you try this, and even tell you that it’s essential, but that’s not quite accurate (`apt` lumps essential and important packages together).

You can also effectively prevent `apt` from updating, upgrading or installing packages, without removing `apt` itself, by disabling all its repositories:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

or less drastically

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list{,.bak}
for file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do if [ -f "${file}" ]; then sudo mv "${file}" "${file}.bak"; fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Even less drastically: Just put a # in front of every line of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

`#deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stable main`